# Using Facebook Registration with customized layout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, registration, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using Facebook Registration in my application. Is it possible to use customized layout instead of Facebook layout in (Registration/ Facebook log in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the layout of the plugin, only the border colour. The reason for this is so that Facebook Users can recognise the plugin and know what to expect.

If you want a custom layout, use Facebook Connect and create your own form and pre-load any data you can from the user's facebook profile.